# Why won't calling a nested function result in returning original function's value?

Tags: python, function, nested-function

Somehow I can't manage to use a previously defined function inside another one. Is that possible?

```
def generate_password(length):
    import random
    password = str()
    alpha_num = [i for i in 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnpqrstuvwxyz23456789']
    while len(password) <= length:
        symbol = random.choice(alpha_num)
        if symbol not in password:
            password += symbol
        else: 
            symbol = random.choice(alpha_num)
    return(password)
        

def generate_passwords(count, length):
    import random
    passlist = []
    for j in range(count):
        generate_password(length)
        if password not in passlist:
            passlist.append(password)
    print(passlist)        

n, m = int(input()), int(input())
generate_passwords(n, m)
```

this code returns an error:

```
 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 24, in <module>
    generate_passwords(n, m)
  File "jailed_code", line 19, in generate_passwords
    if password not in passlist:
NameError: name 'password' is not defined`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  While you have certainly returned ```password``` in ```generate_password```, you haven't assigned the return to a value.

Comment: I have upvoted this because it is a good question - it is clear what the problem is for someone who knows the answer (as ewokx demonstrates). Just a sidenote: Have you tried searching for similar questions? I'm sure there must be several already

Comment: You meant to write: `password = generate_password(length)`

Comment: @ewokx thank you kindly. I didn't realize that assigning the return is needed here!

Comment: @lucidbrot thanks as well. Yeah, I tried looking through similar questions but couldn't find what I needed. As ewokx has pointed out - it was a small and silly mistake on my side.

Comment: @Atagawa Note that `return` is a statement in Python and not a function, so while writing `return(password)` works, the brackets are actually unnecessary and one would usually write `return password`.

Comment: Fair enough, it might be hard to search for if you don't know the solution already. I asked because sometimes new askers do not realize how much has already been asked so they don't search before asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the returned value from the function call `generate_password(length)` into a variable (here, password) to be able to use it further.

```
def generate_password(length):
    import random
    password = str()
    alpha_num = [i for i in 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnpqrstuvwxyz23456789']
    while len(password) <= length:
        symbol = random.choice(alpha_num)
        if symbol not in password:
            password += symbol
        else: 
            symbol = random.choice(alpha_num)
    return(password)
        

def generate_passwords(count, length):
    import random
    passlist = []
    for j in range(count):
        password = generate_password(length)
        if password not in passlist:
            passlist.append(password)
    print(passlist)        

n, m = int(input()), int(input())
generate_passwords(n, m)
```

Answer (score 1):

you're missing `password = generate_password(length)`

Also a set would be a much better data structure (pass_set instead of pass_list) for your operations.

```
import random
import string

def generate_password(length):
    alpha = list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
    return ''.join(random.sample(alpha, length))
        

def generate_passwords(count, length):
    pass_set = set()
    while(len(pass_set) < count):
        pass_set.add(generate_password(length))
    print(pass_set)        

generate_passwords(5, 10)
```